# Ошибка XMLHttpRequest request.open(...) is undefined

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Есть код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var xxx = request.open('GET', 'https://***********.com/text.json', true).getJSON();
      alert(xxx);

    </script>
```

Но консоль браузера выводит ошибку:

```
Uncaught TypeError: request.open(...) is undefined
```

Как это можно исправить? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: где ты взял этот пример с getJSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`XMLHttpRequest.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open) не возвращает никакого значения, поэтому `undefined`, следовательно метода `getJSON()` у результата нет. Как использовать `XMLHttpRequest` см., например, здесь: https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest